# Getting the value selected of DropDownList

Tags: c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a dropdownlist box, from which a user makes a selection.
However, I am not able to retrieve the value of the SelectedItem in the code behind.

How can I get the value selected in the code behind?

```
        if (ddlRegion.SelectedValue = "0")
        {
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('Please select a region')</script>");
            txtEmpID.Text = "";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the code behind"? Is it during the design phase that you cannot see it? Is it when you perform a `post` and want to catch it server side? Is it when you submit it through AJAX or is it in the Javascript code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compare to 0, are you trying to check if the dropdownlist is at its default state (which is the first value)?  If so, [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx) is the property you want, and you want to compare to the integer literal `0`, not the string `"0"`.  Also, it's probably a copy/paste error as it doesn't compile as is, but you want to compare equality with `==`, not make an assignment with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

try SelectedValue property of dropdownlist instead of SelectedItem

Comment: I am using the SelectedValue, but no luck;

Comment: i dont know why, but for general options like Choose something, i use the value of "-1" not "0".

Answer (score 0):

> (SelectedValue from MSDN) This
>   property returns the Value  property
>   of the selected ListItem. The
>   SelectedValue property is commonly
>   used to determine the value of the
>   selected item in the list control. If
>   multiple items are selected, the value
>   of the selected item with the lowest
>   index is returned. If no item is
>   selected, an empty string ("") is
>   returned.

I'd go with the answer "Tanzelax" proposed, but none-the-less, you're comparing against "0" and the Microsoft documentation is telling you to compare against an empty string.